# Unable to find xpath of smart tag

Tags: xpath, smart-tags

I was not able to find the xpath of smart tag:
/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/wl:cache/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/smart:translate

please let me know if anyone have knowledge about it.
Also tried with following and text function.

Comment: Please, take some time to read  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Non html elements (those wit a `prexix`), can be matched by using the `local-name()` function like this:

```
/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/*[local-name()='cache']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/*[local-name()='translate']
```